# Trying to develop closed form solutions of second order DE

Tags: matlab

Basically, I have this function in matlab:

```
function yy = homo2nd(tt,polycc,y0,v0)
    rr = roots(polycc);
    cc = [1 1; rr(1) rr(2)\[y0; v0]];
    yy = cc(1)*exp(rr(1)*tt) + cc(2) * exp(rr(2)*tt);
    yy = round(yy,8);
end
```

I understand that roots takes the roots of an array signifying the coefficients of the left side of the equation. I feed roots and argument like [1 1 1] and it spits out the eigenvalues of that function.

From there I am lost.

I define tt in the command shell like this:

```
tt = linspace(0,2*pi,100).
```

I call homo2nd and feed it arguments (tt,[1 1 1], 1, 1)

When I try to feed roots the argument [1 1 1] like I said I get this error:

```
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.
```

I just need help interpreting the code. Why are the arrays horizontally mismatched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occuring on this line

```
cc = [1 1; rr(1) rr(2)\[y0; v0]];
```

So let's look at this, the `1 1` is fine, it's saying there's a row vector `[1,1]`.

The next part is where the error occurs, the `;` moves us to a second row. The first element of that row is `rr(1)`, this is fine.

However, the second element `rr(2)\[y0; v0]` is using the [mldivide command](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) and the result of this isn't a single element, hence the error.